# ecryptfs - About 200 Passwords to Parse Through

Tags: encryption, ecryptfs, password-recovery

I know all but two characters of my password. I know, I'm an idiot for not writing down my pass immediately after my main board went south on me, but that's water under the bridge.

Anyway, I figure there are about 200 possible passwords that I need to enter, the real password being the need in the 200 password hay stack.

Entering passwords one at a time is incredibly tedious (but an excellent safety feature because ti is so tedious!).  Every time a new password is entered, the software has to spend 30-45 seconds searching for the encrypted drive before allowing me to enter the next password.

Is there any way to automate this process?  Can I copy ten passwords, comma separated, and have it check all ten passwords?

Is there a way to put the possible passwords in a file and then have the software check the passwords in the file?

If nothing else, is there a way to enter passwords without having to scan the HD for the encrypted drive and burning almost a minute between password entries?

Also, pasting a password into the password entry box work or do I manually have to enter it?

Comment: Some more background information:

I'm accessing this drive via USB from a new computer.  The encrypted home is mounting fine and ecryptfs sees the encrypted home directory and allows me to test one password at a time just fine.

The problem is that I don't want to wait about 1 minute between password entries and, even better, I'd like to parse through a list of potential passwords.

Comment: without testing, I suggest that you look into the "expect" package, which provides you a way to programatically interact with programs which expect user interaction. Worst that happens is that you will have to (i) code (ii) wait 200 minutes until the program is finished.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 10

set pwlist [list Pass1 Pass2]      

spawn sudo "ecryptfs-recover-private"

foreach password $pwlist {

expect {
  timeout { send_user "\nTime Out Hit\n"; puts "$password\r"; exit 1 }
  eof { send_user "\nEnd of file hit, attempt terminated \n"; exit 1 }
  
  if {"Try to recover this directory? [Y/n]: "} {
     send "y\r"
  } elseif {"Do you know your LOGIN passphrase? [Y/n] "} {
     send "y\r" 
  } elseif {"Passphrase: "} {
     send "$password\r" 
  } else {
     puts "end of expect if statement"
  }

}

}

Comment: I've moved this question over to linuxquestions.org

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/expect-tcl-programming-pproblem-4175455604/#post4919679

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this question is essentially the same as the solution to this "challenge" I posted on my blog several years ago.  *(Note, I'm the author of Ubuntu's Encrypted Home Directory feature, and the maintainer of [eCryptfs](http://ecryptfs.org).)*

You can find the challenge [here](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2009/01/daemon-challenge-3-how-efficient-are.html), and the solution [here](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2009/01/daemon-challenge-3-we-have-winner.html).